# Recursion in Interface methods

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method inside a searchTree class, and for some reason, the methods are looking outside the class in the interface for the definition of the method rather than looking at themselves. Here are some snippets of the code:

in Main class:

```
    public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BinarySearchTreeInterface1<T>, BinarySearchTreeInterface2<T>{`
```

recursive method within Main:

```
    public int getHeight(){
        if (isEmpty()){
            return 0;
        }else{
            int height = 1 + Math.max(this.getLeftSubTree().getHeight(),
                                      this.getRightSubTree().getHeight());
            return height;
        }
   }`
```

As you can see I have two interface classes. The error underlines getHeight() and states:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method getHeight()
location: interface BinarySearchTreeInterface1<T>
where T is a type-variable:
 T extends Comparable<T> declared in class BinarySearchTree
```

I have 5 recursive methods that were shown in the Interface2 file and all of them are getting this same erorr. Thanks for any assistance.

Update:  I am hesitant to post the Interface classes as they are from a university class and I don't wish to upset the instructor. The ironic thing is, the non-recursive methods work just fine. Here is a small part of what the Interface2 file shows:

```
public interface BinarySearchTreeInterface2<T>{

    public int getNumberOfNodes();

    public int getHeight();
```

Comment: That's not really recursion then.

Comment: I just want to get the error to go away so that I can test my code. The instructor made it work somehow, as he has ran this and given us the answers so we can verify our code is correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's not quite recursion. It would be recursive if the method literally called itself within the context of the same object, such as `this.getHeight()`. In your case, you are calling the same method, but on a different object. I don't fullyunderstand the situation though; did you create the `getHeight` method for BOTH of your interfaces?

Comment: Show us how the interfaces are defined, and particularly where and how the getLeftSubTree and getRightSubTree methods are defined.

Comment: To make the error go away, only call methods that are allowed by the type of variable that you're making the call on.

Comment: @Teeg: I don't see why it wouldn't be recursion. The method calls itself until it reaches a final condition. The final condition being that the node on which it's called is empty.

Comment: @Teeg, the recursive methods are all listed in the Interface2 file only. I'm not sure why he split them up, but obviously they work as he got output and lists it for us to test our's with.

I've added a snippet of the Interface class in the listing above.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually, on second thought, this probably would be considered recursion. I made the sudden assumption it could only be considered for the SAME method call on the SAME object; in Kent's case he's calling the SAME method on DIFFERENT objects. In reality, the method code is not duplicated for each instance of the class, so I guess it would be considered recursive after all. Ultimately, its all semantics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `getLeftSubTree()` returns a `BinarySearchTreeInterface1<T>`. But getHeight() is defined in `BinarySearchTreeInterface2<T>`, so the method getHeight() can't be called on the result of `getLeftSubTree()`.

You might be able to get the program compile by overriding the `getLeftSubTree()` method like this:

```
public BinarySearchTree<T> getLeftSubTree() {
    ...
}
```

Of course, the same must be done with `getRightSubTree()`.

Comment: beat me to the punch by a few seconds. Will leave my answer for a while

Comment: OMG!! I went back and looked at the method from his class notes, and he has it implemented in the Interface class as BinarySearchTreeInterface1<T> yet the notes from class show the coding as BinarySearchTree<T>, just as you stated. Changed that code and it removed the error.  Now to see if my code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the type that `getLeftSubTree()` **declares** to return does not implement `getHeight()`.

Remember that the type *declared* to be returned by a method can be a supertype (for instance, and interface) of the type it *actually* returns. So it is possible to declare
`BinarySearchTreeInterface1<T>  getLeftSubTree()` (which does not implement `BinarySearchTreeInterface2`),
and actually return a `BinarySearchTree<T>` (which does) -- and get the error you describe above.